# sql query and sum the two fields

Tags: sql, sum

I want to display unit price, quantity but my problem is I want to multiply the unit price * quantity. How to combine this 3 fields? I want the result like this:

```
UNITPRICE         QUANTITY             AMOUNT
2                                 3                              6
```

2X3 equals 6.. please help me how to query this..

thank you newbie in multiplying table

Comment: Hint:  `unitprice * quantity as amount`.

Answer (score 1):

I made this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a3ad/1) for you. Perhaps it will help you.

```
select 
  UNITPRICE,
  QUANTITY,
  UNITPRICE * QUANTITY as [Amount]
from data
```